# Xelatex and french through polyglossia: how to have the french punctuation even with inline mathematics

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, french

When I use xelatex, and polyglossia to deal with the french punctuation, I get the right spacing with the pure text, but not when I put mathematics in my text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\newcommand{\fff}{f; f ;«f» « f »; $\epsilon$; A: Aspace : $Amath$: $Amathspace$ :}


\begin{document}
\fff


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\begin{document}

f; f ; «f» « f »; $\epsilon$; A: Aspace : $Amath$: $Amathspace$ :

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Indeed it works with texlive 2015, but not texlive 2016 which I forgot that I used for this document.

Comment: @user1283885 I'll test it later, but questions about pretest versions are better addressed to the mailing lists or developers' sites

Comment: @user1283885 The `gloss-french.ldf` file should be updated to use 4095 instead of 255 in four places.

Comment: @user1283885 https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/145